# Defining and searching sets on correlated orders in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, containers, binary-search-tree

I have a collection of `n` objects. Each object has 2 numeric attributes `A` and `B`.
I know that orders on `A` and `B` are fully correlated: `obj1.A > obj2.A` if and only if `obj1.B > obj2.B`.

If I implement the collection as a set sorted by `A`,
I can support in `O(log n)` the following operations:

- insertion
- deletion
- lower_bound on `A`

But searching `std::lower_bound` on attribute `B` will be linear because sets do not support RandomAccessIterators. 
I know that I could define my own implementation of binary trees (ex: red-black or AVL) that would store in each node both the `A` and `B` values. This way I could have `O(log n)` for all 4 operations.

Is there a simpler (higher level) approach to support efficiently the 4 operations (search on both attributes, insertion and deletion)?

Comment: Do you have access to c++14?

Comment: Yes. A C++14 solution is fine with me.

Comment: Take a look at [`std::set::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/lower_bound) If you make your class compareable against a `B`, you may be able to get what you want. It will probably take a small helper class (a wrapper around an integer you'll compare `B` to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of what I rambled about in my comments:

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

namespace test {
    struct test {
        int A;
        int B;
    };

    bool operator< (test const& lhs, test const& rhs) {
        return lhs.A < rhs.A;
    }

    struct test_B { double B; };

    bool operator< (test const& lhs, test_B const& rhs) {
        return lhs.B < rhs.B;
    }

    bool operator< (test_B const& lhs, test const& rhs) {
        return lhs.B < rhs.B;
    }
}

int main() {

    std::set<test::test, std::less<void>> example {
     {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}
    };

    std::cout << example.lower_bound<test::test_B>({3.5})->B;

    return 0;
}
```

c++14 allows for sets to call `lower_bound` on anything they can compare against their key. Now, all I did was create a wrapper type that is comparable to my original structure, but it looks at the `B` value. Effectively, I made `set::lower_bound` look at `B` instead of `A` as it does by default.

Since your numeric keys are correlated, I suspect you'd get the promised set performance of `lower_bound`.

You can take a look at it [here](http://ideone.com/K9JbpB)

Comment: @JosephStack, be sure to turn on -std=c++14, and that you define your set with `std::less<void>`

Comment: Ok was just an eclipse pb.
Now, the trick of using distinct template parameters for the `set::lower_bound` and for the underlying `set` works in practice on my computer. But would you know if this behaviour is guaranteed by the standard?

Comment: @JosephStack [since c++14](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/lower_bound). It's all in the added function template. The point of this addition is to avoid creating temporary objects if your key is just one field. However... It permits any type to be used in the comparison, as long as the comparison is possible. The one caveat is that it has to be the same order type (from a mathematical standpoint), which I believe is your case.

Comment: Would you also know if a similar trick can work for std::map? (if A is the key and the value is B (or value {A, B} but B cannot belong to key).

Comment: @JosephStack it should, again so long as the order type is preserved. So if you map `{A,B}` to something, it will work almost exactly the same.

Comment: The point is: I can only map {A} to something. In fact A is coordinate and B is slope of convexhull points in the application I have in mind, so B can only belong to value (because inserting a point modifies a few slopes), though I want to search by A and B.

Comment: @JosephStack Then I fear this trick won't work. You may refer to Maxims answer for a reference to boosts multi-index.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using boost multi-index to have more than one index in a container.

See [Multiple sorts on a single set](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#multiple_sort) tutorial.